# Add a number to "Number[]" in a loop

Tags: java, numbers

Its a pretty simple question, how do i add a number to "Number[]" one at a time?

Its a simplified example:
normally to fill number we do this:

```
Number[] series1Numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

But how do i add a number to the end of this? like this should result in the same as above:

```
for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
nextNumber = i;

Number[] seriesOfNumbers = {+ nextNumber}; //This dosnt work, so i need to change it somehow
}
```

Comment: You cannot add elements to an already defined array using array literal. You need to use `List`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the size already, it's easy:

```
Number[] seriesOfNumbers = new Number[9];
for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
    nextNumber = i;
    seriesOfNumbers[i - 1] = nextNumber;
}
```

However, generally it would be better to use a `List`:

```
List<Number> seriesOfNumbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
    nextNumber = i;
    seriesOfNumbers.add(nextNumber);
}
```

Arrays always have a fixed size - once you've created the array object, you can't add or remove elements; you can only set and fetch them. `ArrayList<T>` still uses an array as a backing store, but creates a new array (and copies existing values) when it needs to in order to accommodate more items.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Collection` instead of an Array:

```
List<Number> series1Numbers = new ArrayList<Number>

 for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
  series1Numbers.add(i);
```

and if you need the array

```
Number []series1NumbersArray = new Number[series1Numbers.size()];
series1Numbers.toArray(series1NumbersArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be:

```
Number[] seriesOfNumbers = new Number[9];

for(int i=0; i<seriesOfNumbers.length; i++)
{
    seriesOfNumbers[i] = i+1;

}
```